# Scaling out Kafka Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working with a Kafka consumer group and need to have more than 50 consumers in a single group. As I understand it, this is limited by the number of partitions in Kafka.

How can I handle message ordering when using more than 50 consumers in a Kafka consumer group? Are there any best practices or specific configuration changes that can be made to ensure that messages are processed in the correct order?

I can do it by handling with new local queue and with an algorithm like consistent-hashing but I don't want to create it from scratch.
My another solution was to writing a router and create sub topics but I think it's not a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Kafka only provides ordering within partitions, and that's it. The ordering is only by offset, and it is unclear what you mean by "correct" in this case.

If you want any further stronger guarantees, you'll need to "fan in" your consumers to one source, such as a database table perhaps, or in-memory (priority)queue as you say, and sort-by your necessary attributes.

---

The best way that Kafka consumers can scale is when all partitions are considered equal. If you really need to create a "sequence of tasks" between topics or partitions within them, you may want to look into async messaging patterns such as Distributed Sagas.

In the event you need to schedule messages between partitions, you will want to use `consumer.assign` function to specific partitions, as well as manage offsets on your own, as this will no longer use a consumer group.

Comment: assume that I have a message-id that I route to a specific partition, I need to handle change of message by one consumer (I have a stateful system), and I want to scale it out more than 50. 
I understand your solution but as I mentioned I don't want to do it from scratch

Comment: You can use Kafka Streams/Spark/Flink to do stateful processing, but I still think you want multiple topics to designate logical ordering, since all partitions of any topic will be consumed in parallel, by default. Besides, you also will need to implement that "route to specific partition" logic "from scratch" as well (Kafka already does this by hashing the record key)